# How to access subclasses from a superclass in Java?

Tags: java, class, object

I have a question about subclasses and superclasses. In a project I'm working on, I have a superclass called "Team" and some subclasses called "TeamBlue","TeamRed"... Also, all of these subclasses have static fields and methods in them.

My question is: how do I store any subclass object (either TeamBlue or TeamRed) into a "Team" object? if this makes sense.

here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

Team  team = new BlueTeam(); <-- storing any color team into a "team" object

this is a short version of the code I have:

```
class Team {
    //empty class used for binding all the team classes
}

class BlueTeam extends Team {
    public static List<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
}

class PlayerData {
    Team playerTeam;
    public PlayerData(Team tm){
        playerTeam = tm;
    }
    playerTeam.players // I want to access any subclass that is stored into this "myTeam" object and access its players list
}


class createData {
    List<PlayerData> data = new ArrayList<PlayerData>();
    // this is what I've tried but I get a null exception
    Team team = new BlueTeam();
    data.add(new PlayerData(team));
}
```

Comment: You could create an abstract method `Team.getPlayers()` and make sure the subclasses implement/override this method.

Comment: no that cannot happen, you can treat blueTeam as a team, but you cannot treat blueTeam as redTeam or vice versa neither can you treat team as blueTeam, that doesn't make sense at all... in convention we call parent class as superclass and child class as subclass, but mathematically (in terms of sets) subclass is actually a superset of superclass... I hope you get my point...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not object-oriented! Why does the blue team have a static list of players? Why is it public? You should use a getter and override the method.

```
abstract class Team {
    // if there is a sensible default return then use it and the class needn't be abstract
    abstract List<String> getPlayers(); 
}

class BlueTeam extends Team {
    private final List<String> players = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    List<String> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Team team = new BlueTeam();
List<String> bluePlayers = team.getPlayers();
```

Comment: aren't other teams supposed to have a `List<String> players`? isn't it worth moving the field into the parent class?

Comment: Why does BlueTeam even need its own class? Why can't it just be an instance of Team?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ask him. He has decided that it requires inheritance. I simply provided what I think are the minimum set of changes in order for his design to work.

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely doing class hierarchy wrong. Blue is not a property of a team, colour is. Meaning that instead of subclassing your `Team` for every possible colour, you should have a property called `colour` or `name` in Team and assign "blue" or "red" to that property in the instance of Team that represents the blue or red team.

Comment: What if the behaviour of the blue team is different from a normal team? Then its no longer just a property.

Comment: @Michael That is something that probably can be just as well or maybe even better solved using composition than inheritance

Comment: @Michael For example, if we're talking about how a team reacts to an event, such as enemy appearing (I'm getting a PvP vibe from the red and blue teams), the strategy-design pattern could be used. A team is given a set of algorithms, that are implemented as classes that implement a common interface, that define their behaviour. The behaviour thus becomes a property of the team.

Comment: the key word there is 'could'. In your answer you have assumed that blue-ness is just some property, but it could easily bring with it behaviour. Yes, composition is one way to accomplish that, but it doesn't make inheritance "wrong" like you said it was

Comment: If you want to go down that path you might as well say "it can't be bad because it passes the compiler". However, there are other things, which have been extensively discussed already, that affect the "goodness" of code.